# Как разбить строку по параметрам на разные массивы?

Tags: массивы, php, файлы

> version = ‘1.3.15’ source.id =
> ‘1’ source.path = ‘some/path’
> login.remember = ‘1’ login.name =
> ‘userName’ login.password = ‘password’
> awful.layout = ‘split’
> awful.layout.suit = ‘tile’

в такой вид необходим

```
$config = array(‘version’ => ‘1.3.15’, 
‘source’  => array(‘id’ => ‘1’,‘path’ => ‘some/path’,),’
    login=>array(remember=>1,name=username,password=password)
    awful=>array(layot=>split,  
            awful.layot=>array(suit=>tjtle))
```

не понимаю как разделять те значения что до равно в одну часть а что после в другую часть и как раздеть те значения что с точкой(как awful.layout и awful.layout.suit )

пока вот что получается:

```
$lines = file_get_contents('file.txt',  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
echo("<b>вот содержимое \$lines= $lines</b>");
echo"<br>";
$res = explode(' = ', $lines);

foreach ($res as $line_num => $line) {

    echo "Строка #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";

}
```

а вот вывод:

```
вот содержимое $lines= version = ‘1.3.15’ source.id = ‘1’ source.path = ‘some/path’ login.remember = ‘1’ login.name = ‘userName’ login.password = ‘password’ awful.layout = ‘split’ awful.layout.suit = ‘tile’
Строка #0 : version
Строка #1 : ‘1.3.15’ source.id
Строка #2 : ‘1’ source.path
Строка #3 : ‘some/path’ login.remember
Строка #4 : ‘1’ login.name
Строка #5 : ‘userName’ login.password
Строка #6 : ‘password’ awful.layout
Строка #7 : ‘split’ awful.layout.suit
Строка #8 : ‘tile’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str="Ваша строка";
$str_array=explode(" ", $str);

foreach($str_array as $k=>$v){
    $tmp1=explode("=", $v);
    $tmp1[0]=trim($tmp1[0]);
    if(strpos($tmp1[0], ".")) {
        $tmp2=explode(".", $tmp1[0]);
        $res[$tmp2[0]][$tmp2[1]]=$tmp1[1];
    }else{
        $res[$tmp1[0]]=$tmp1[1];
    }
}
```

Как-то так, не проверял...

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай
Как правильно записать эти строки? 
>$res[$tmp2[0]][$tmp2[1]]=$tmp1[1];
>   }else{
>       $res[$tmp1[0]]=$tmp1[1];

а то ругается

    Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\yii\s.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\yii\s.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\yii\s.php on line 14
.............................

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\yii\s.php on line 14

Comment: это обычные предупреждения.

Comment: @Node_pro но не отключать же их

Comment: да как же вывести T_T